# How to get Dock to work with AppImage Hyper?

Tags: unity, ubuntu-dock, dock, desktop-apps

I had an older version of vercel Hyper (xterm) working and on the dock.  I deleted that folder and added a new one (with a different path).  The dock doesn't seem able to find it.

I can run hyper from the command line fine, but not from the dock.

I tried running it from the command line, and then "add to favorites" - but clicking on the icon from the dock still doesn't work.

How can I edit the path to an app on the dock?  Also, when I click Details, it shows me details for "HyperRogue" game - not the actual app.  Isn't there a way to show and edit the paths for apps on the dock?

Likewise, when I go to the launcher and type "hyper" - it ignores my path and tries to find HypeRogue, despite having `hyper` in `/usr/local/bin` in my `PATH`.

Comment: Which dock are you using? What is your version of Ubuntu? Which desktop environment?

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi Just upgraded to Ubuntu 22.  The default, which I think is Unity.  (I don't see an identifier, but it says "Activities" in the upper left corner).

Comment: The default desktop in Ubuntu 22.04 is GNOME (which Ubuntu customizes to resemble Unity)